# How to append particular CSS shapes to data in D3.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, d3.js

I have the cloud shape in the following `CSS` code:

```
.cloud {
width: 200px; height: 60px;
background: #fff;

border-radius: 200px;
-moz-border-radius: 200px;
-webkit-border-radius: 200px;

position: relative; 
}

.cloud:before, .cloud:after {
content: '';
position: absolute; 
background: #fff;
width: 100px; height: 80px;
position: absolute; top: 60px; left: 10px;

border-radius: 100px;
-moz-border-radius: 100px;
-webkit-border-radius: 100px;

-webkit-transform: rotate(30deg);
transform: rotate(30deg);
-moz-transform: rotate(30deg);
}

.cloud:after {
width: 120px; height: 120px;
top: -55px; left: auto; right: 15px;
}
```

What I would like to do is to append some data to divs that their attributes are the `.cloud` in `CSS`. Here is my code in `D3.js`

```
var dataset = [1, 2, 3];
//Create SVG object
var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg").attr({width: 800, height: 800});

svg.selectAll("div").data(dataset).enter().append("div");
```

What I've understood so far is since there is no `div` on the page, D3.js will bind each element of the array to a selection of divs that do not exist yet and append them to cloud class in `CSS`. Unfortunately, I do not see the clouds shapes on the browser. I tried the same D3.js code with `circle` in CSS and it was simply working fine but not with the cloud class in CSS. What am I missing in here? Could any please help me with this issue? Thanks in advance.

Comment: You need to do `.append("div").attr("class", "cloud")` to set the CSS class. There's no `cloud` element.

Comment: Thanks, Lars for your help. I have fixed my code as follows: svg.selectAll("div").data(dataset).enter().append("div").attr("class","cloud"); Unfortunately I did not see what I am expecting. Do you think I am still having something wrong?

Comment: Ah, you can't append `div`s to an SVG -- just append them to the body: http://jsfiddle.net/k8p0ja4h/

Comment: Lars. Thank you very much for your help. One more question please. Is there any possibility to append the shapes to SVG? The problem is I am working on SVG and would like to append them to that SVG. Do you think there is any way to do so? Once again, thank you very much for your help. It is very much appreciated.

Comment: Well then you would need to append e.g. a `rect` element.

Comment: So does that mean I should append rect first and then append the cloud div to that rect element, Lars?

Comment: No. Append the `rect` element and assign the `cloud` class to it.

Comment: I have appended a rect element and assigned cloud class to it. Unfortunately, I can't see the clouds. Here is my code: svg.append("rect").attr("x", 10)
                           .attr("y", 30)
                            .attr("width", 100).attr("height", 50)
                            .style("fill","red")
                      .attr("class","cloud"); Lars, I am so sorry for keeping distracting you. If you have any more tips or guidance, please provide me. I would be the most thankful to you.

Comment: It's possible that not all of your CSS is supported in SVG.